# Spotfire Graphical Table - Calculate across Columns

Tags: spotfire

Essentially I want the end user to be able to select 2 date ranges and have a report show the ID counts in those 2 periods and the subsequent difference.

I currently have a graphical table with 2 columns for count(ID). Each Count(ID) is attached to a separate filtering scheme and date filter. However, I can't figure out how to get the difference between those 2 values.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Pic of my current set up]

Comment: Interesting approach to this. I can't think of a way that this will work in an expression without using a script. What you could do, however, is use property controls for your date ranges instead of using a filter control. This will allow you to use the expression in your third column, giving you the desired results.

Comment: How would you go about creating a double slider? The property control only has the option for a single slider and I need to be able to select a start and end date.